# In a database of school social network, how to add a _question in _question board

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008-r2

Every student has ID, and is Linked to a school. The school has a question board which has has questions. I as student want to add a question to the board of my school

I tried this query but it didn't work

```
CREATE PROC ask_question
    @question VARCHAR(100), 
    @my_id INTEGER
AS
BEGIN
    EXEC InsertQuestion @id, @question, SELECT D.ID FROM Discussions D WHERE (D.school_id = SELECT S.school_id FROM Students S WHERE S.ID = @my_id)
END
```

The `InsertQuestion` procedure :

```
CREATE PROC InsertQuestion
   @asker INTEGER, 
   @q VARCHAR(100), 
   @discussion INTEGER
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Questions (asker_id , question , discussion_id)
    VALUES (@asker , @q , @discussion)
END
```

Comment: Any answers to this question would be too specific to help anyone but you. Consider reposting the question in a more generalized fashion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **cannot** have a `SELECT` statement directly in an `EXEC` call to provide a parameter - you need to do this first, store the value into a SQL Server variable, and **then** call the procedure.

So you need to change your code to:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ask_question
    @question VARCHAR(100), 
    @my_id INTEGER
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @DiscussionID INT

    SELECT @DiscussionID = d.ID 
    FROM dbo.Discussions d 
    INNER JOIN dbo.Students s ON s.school_id = d.school_id
    WHERE S.ID = @my_id

    EXEC InsertQuestion @id, @question, @DiscussionID
END
```